# Plot data on 3D model using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, patch

I have patched 3D structure. I have coordinates of all vertices.
Now, I want to plot data that corresponds to each vertex. What kind of function should I look out for?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try `scatter3` if you want to plot the points.